# How to upload my APIREST in NodeJS (with Mongoose) to Google Cloud Platformn?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, google-cloud-platform

I have developed an API in NodeJs and Express, with MongoDB database, and I want to upload my API to Google Cloud Platform. I've checked some tutorials but I don't know what is the best way to upload it.

I'm using Robo3T to manage my database, I saw if I want to upload my database I need bitnami and create a MEAN project to have the database in the Google compute engine, and then, the NodeJs code in the app engine.

Is that correct?

If you can send me a good tutorial or something it will be helpful to me.